# My Query Works in Database but Not in My Script

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

I have a dropdown list populated by this query:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT CAST(MR_ID AS INT) AS MR_ID FROM Stage_Rebate_Index";
```

Then I had a table that would display values in a table based on the selection of the dropdown. I used this query to do so. Everything worked!

```
$sql_one = "SELECT CAST(Supp_ID AS INT) AS Supp_ID, CAST(MR_ID AS INT) AS MR_ID FROM Stage_Rebate_Index WHERE MR_ID = '$mr_id'";
```

However, I had to make some changes and this is the query I need to populate my dropdown.

```
$sql = "
SELECT DISTINCT
       CONCAT(CAST(t1.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', COALESCE(t2.MR_Name, '')) AS MR_ID,
       t1.MR_ID AS sort_column 
FROM Stage_Rebate_Index t1
      LEFT JOIN Stage_Rebate_Master t2
         ON t2.MR_ID = t1.MR_ID
ORDER BY sort_column";
```

And this is the query I use to display the values in a table based on the selection of the dropdown. However, now it doesnt work whatsoever. Anytime a selection is made, the only thing displayed is the table headers. Why is this!? This is driving me crazy, I can't figure this out.

```
$sql_one = "
SELECT 
       CONCAT(CAST(t1.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', COALESCE(t2.MR_Name, '')) AS MR_ID,
       t1.MR_ID AS sort_column, 
       CAST(Supp_ID as INT) AS Supp_ID
FROM Stage_Rebate_Index t1
      LEFT JOIN Stage_Rebate_Master t2
         ON t2.MR_ID = t1.MR_ID
WHERE  
  CONCAT(CAST(t1.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', t2.MR_Name) = LTRIM(RTRIM('$mr_id'))
ORDER BY sort_column";
```

EDIT:
My test-table.php script that is called from an ajax function...

```
<?php
$host="xxxxxxxx"; 
$dbName="xxxxx"; 
$dbUser="xxxxxxxxxxx"; 
$dbPass="xxxxxxxxx";

$mr_id = $_POST['mr_name'];

$dbh = new PDO( "sqlsrv:server=".$host."; Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);
$dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
//$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT CAST(MR_ID AS INT) AS MR_ID FROM Stage_Rebate_Index WHERE MR_ID = '$mr_id'";
//$sql_one = "SELECT CAST(Supp_ID AS INT) AS Supp_ID, CAST(MR_ID AS INT) AS MR_ID FROM Stage_Rebate_Index WHERE MR_ID = '$mr_id'";

/*$sql_one = "
SELECT 
       CONCAT(CAST(t1.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', COALESCE(t2.MR_Name, '')) AS MR_ID,
       t1.MR_ID AS sort_column, 
       CAST(Supp_ID as INT) AS Supp_ID
FROM Stage_Rebate_Index t1
      LEFT JOIN Stage_Rebate_Master t2
         ON t2.MR_ID = t1.MR_ID
WHERE  
  CONCAT(CAST(t1.MR_ID AS INT),' - ', t2.MR_Name) = LTRIM(RTRIM('$mr_id'))
ORDER BY sort_column";*/

$sql_one = "
SELECT ID_Name, CAST(Supp_ID as INT) as Supp_ID
FROM Stage_Rebate_Index
WHERE ID_Name = LTRIM(RTRIM('$mr_id'));";

//echo $sql_one;

//$users = $dbh->query($sql);
$users_one = $dbh->query($sql_one);
?>

<html>
    <body>

        <!-- Table -->
<p> 
    <div id="table_div">
        <table border="1" id="index_table" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
            <thead>
                <tr class="ui-widget-header">
                <td>MR ID</td>
                <td>Supplier ID</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php foreach($users_one->fetchAll() as $supp) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="mr_id"><?php echo $supp['ID_Name'];?></td>
                <td class="supp_id"><?php echo $supp['Supp_ID'];?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </table>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?
Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I have, and I also just used that code and there were no errors, nothing.

Comment: A good approach whenever you have such situations, would be to try to output your SQL in your php script and then run that SQL directly in a database console. It might be that the SQL in your script is 'rendered' wrong

Comment: I have done that as well. I echo out my sql statement and use it in my database console and it works just fine

Comment: How do you execute this query in PHP?

Comment: I use `$users_one = $dbh->query($sql_one);` and then use a foreach loop to loop in the values

Comment: post your full php code instead.

Comment: added my php code as an edit

Comment: not sure why this had a vote down. this seems interesting to know for any level of programmer!